# Symfony - resize image after upload

Tags: image, symfony

I have the following problem, uploads a file using symfony, it is moved with the original resolution and extension. And now I would like to create a second file, which is a copy of the first one but with a resolution of 320px x 60px and that it should be in the name, ie how the original file has the name:
my_images.png I would like the copy to be named my_images_320x60.png

After correct upload, my picture is available at http: //localhost/uploads/i/my_images.png

My upload looks like this:

```
$logoFile = $this->getValidatorParameter('logo_file');
$storage = $this->get('file.event.storage');
$file = $storage->upload($logoFile->getValue());
```

Anyone have any idea how to do it? The image is copied, I have a path to it, but I can not change its resolution and name :(

Comment: Check out ImageMagick with the Imagick php extension

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[intervention/image](https://github.com/Intervention/image) works very well with Symfony, for example:

```
// open an image file
$img = Image::make('public/foo.jpg');

// resize image instance
$img->resize(320, 240);

// save image in desired format
$img->save('public/bar.jpg');
```

Comment: Works amazing :) Thanks :)